# SQL: How to to SUM two values from different tables

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sql

[image]

I want to find `SUM` of Table 1 & Table 2 in Result Table. As shown in the above Result table.

I have tried with the query below

```sql
Select
  Sum(t2.[Lead Score] + t1.[Lead Score]) [Lead Score],
  t2.SubscriberKey
from [Table1] t2
left join [Table2]  t1
  on t2.SubscriberKey= t1.SubscriberKey
group by t2.SubscriberKey
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so others can easily see this has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could build the sum of a subquery that combines the results of two tables using `UNION`.

```sql
SELECT
  r.SubscriberKey [SubscriberKey],
  sum(r.[Lead Score]) [Lead Score]
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      SubscriberKey,
      [Lead Score]
    FROM
      Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      SubscriberKey,
      [Lead Score]
    FROM
      Table2
  ) as r
GROUP BY SubscriberKey
```